# C: scanf and strings

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have problem with scanf and two strings.

```
char city1[11], city2[11];
for(int i = 0; i < (m + k); i++) {
scanf("%s %s", city1, city2);
}
```

I should read (m + k) thimes two strings - names of citites. The problem is that when I write some strings an press enter nothing hapen. Pointer is on the screen but I can't do anything. I tried to write something with printf after scanf but it doesn't work. :/

More code:

```
int n, m, k;
do {
    scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &m, &k);
} while(n < 2 || n > 10001 || -1 < m || m > 100001 || -1 < k || k > 100001);

city* cities = (city*)malloc(n*sizeof(city));
path* paths = (path*)malloc((m + k)*sizeof(path));
int addCities = 0;
char city1[11], city2[11];
for(int i = 0; i < (m + k); i++) {
    scanf("%s %s", city1, city2);
    printf("ok");

    if(addCities < n && !isListed(cities, n, city1)) { // if city1 is not into cities
        // add it
        strcpy(cities[addCities].name, city1);
        cities[addCities].prev = NO_PARENT;
        addCities++;
    }
    paths[i].i = getCityNumber(cities, n, city1); // number of city1

    if(addCities < n && !isListed(cities, n, city2)) { // if city2 is not into cities
        // add it
        strcpy(cities[addCities].name, city2);
        cities[addCities].prev = NO_PARENT;
        addCities++;
    }
    paths[i].j = getCityNumber(cities, n, city1); // number of city2

    if(i >= m)
        scanf("%d", &paths[i].price);
}
```

Comment: Please show a complete example.

Comment: This code snippet is 'C' like. Please edit your tag

Comment: can you please give the full code ? what are and where are defined m nad k ?

Comment: I add a full main function. ;)

Comment: Don't cast the output value of `malloc`.

Comment: ALWAYS check the return value of `scanf` to make sure it read the number of items you wanted and didn't get stuck on some unexpected input character

Comment: And please just avoid using `scanf` in general. http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: This bug is one reason why I **hate** reversed relations, as in `-1 < m` where the constant is the left operator and the variable the right. If you had written `m > -1` it would have **jumped at you**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this condition means not what you expect:

```
while(n < 2 || n > 10001 || -1 < m || m > 100001 || -1 < k || k > 100001)
```

This will ask you for n, m, k while this condition is true.
If you enter n=3,m=-1,k=-1 it will pass next.

What n, m, k ranges are valid for input?

If n >=2 && n <= 10001, m >= -1 && m <= 100001, k >= -1 && k <= 100001, then
valid loop is

```
do {
    scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &m, &k);
} while ( n < 2 || n > 10001 || m < -1 || m > 100001 || k < -1 || k > 100001 );
```

Comment: In particular, the `for` loop will never do anything, as `m` and `k` must both be negative to get out of the `do`..`while` loop.

Comment: n must be from 2 to 10001 and m,k - from -1 to 100001. If they not in this interval, I must enter them again. I think that it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced (m+h) with the number 10 since you don't reference m or h in your code.  Here is some code that looks like what you want to do.  This code works.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  char city1[11], city2[11];

  for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    scanf("%s %s",city1,city2);
    printf("city1: %s\n",city1);
    printf("city2: %s\n",city2);
  }


}
```

The output is like this.  I entered a b  c asdf  c  d

```
a b
city1: a
city2: b
c asdf
city1: c
city2: asdf
c
d
city1: c
city2: d
```

I hope this helps!